# Change stack location in C in Kernel

Tags: c, assembly, stack, kernel, inline-assembly

I'm writing a toy kernel and I need to change the location of my kernel's stack to a more suitable location. Upon startup, I initialize a temporary stack in assembly using the following:

```
section .bss
align 4
STACKSIZE equ 0x4000 ;16k
stack_top: resb STACKSIZE ;Reserve 16k stack
```

and then in my main function:

```
mov esp, stack_top + STACKSIZE
push eax ;push magic number
push ebx ;push multiboot_info_t address
call kmain ;Call C kernel main
```

I am using `nasm` and `gcc` to compile.

My kernel is growing to the point where I'm about to have a stack overflow (no pun intended), and I need to relocate the stack to another (larger) location. I use GRUB as my bootloader and I can find usable chunks of memory by reading the `multiboot_info_t` struct in my C kernel. Is there a way to "move" the stack to a larger area of memory using C (inline assembly)? Or is this entirely impossible and my only choice is to increase the initial stack size? I have tried the following already:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("movl $0x200000, %esp");
```

but no luck. 0x200000 is a random location after my kernel that I selected, I intend on moving it to a more appropriate location once I figure out if this is even possible. Thanks!

Comment: Depends on your overall design.  For instance,at some point in your startup, probably earlier than later, you  could create kernel services, including initializing your kernels memory manager to, well, manage all the remaining memory.  You could then allocate a Thread Conrol Block and stack, setup an interrupt stack frame, load your stack pointer with the frame address and IRET to it.   That thread then carries on with system startup. You could then use your orignal stack space as a kernel stack - something to swap to when the thread, and later threads, make syscalls.

Comment: Generally, you can have pointers to stack-variables. Consequently, moving the stack will cause those pointers to point to the wrong thing.

Comment: Since you are using multiboot, and the code given i'd venture to guess you are writing 32 bit code in protected mode. Have you considered creating an entry in your GDT for the stack where the base is 0x200000 (and an appropriate limit). Of course I don't know your current memory layout and your stack might be relative to DS, but hard to tell from given info. Also curious what *but no luck*. 0x200000 is a random location  meant. How did it not work?

Comment: I'd of course set up the stack before calling any C functions. That could be done in whatever module contains the entry point that gets executed by the mulitboot manager.

Comment: Whatever you  do, It's unlikely that you will get away without any assembler at all. As others have suggested, you should not attempt to actually move stacks. OS kernels don't keep persistent data on stacks anyway.  When it's entered on a syscall, you can switch to the kernel stack with the kernel SP at the top of its space every time.

Comment: Ok, I figured as much. It makes sense that doing so may corrupt pointers etc. To answer Michael Petch's question, it did not work because after making the call to change the value of ESP, when outputting the value of it to the screen using a printf style function (to verify ESP was actually changed) it gave me a random symbol and a letter `s`. Obviously it should have been `0x200000`.

Comment: I suppose I will just increase the initial size of the stack as the simple solution.

Comment: What are you doing that 16k isn't enough stack space for kernel startup / initialisation?!

Comment: Nothing now, I still have a good amount left but by the time I implement the memory manager and hardware abstraction layers etc. I'd like to have a bit more elbow room.